# Retrieving a single Object inside an Array using the MongoDB Mongoose driver

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that looks similar to this:

```
{
    'user_id':'{1231mjnD-32JIjn-3213}',
    'name':'John',
    'campaigns':
        [
            {
                'campaign_id':3221,
                'start_date':'12-01-2012',
                'worker_id': '00000'
            },
            {
                'campaign_id':3222,
                'start_date':'13-01-2012',
                'worker_id': '00000'
            },
            ...
            etc
            ...
        ]
}
```

I am trying to retrieve an object in the `campaigns` array.
For example, I would like to find the `campaign_id` under `name: "John"` given a positional element of, say, 7.
In other words, find and return the `campaign_id` at position 7 in the array `campaigns`.

Using the mongoose driver:

`camps.findOne({name: 'John'}, {name: 1, "campaigns.7.campaign_id": 1}, function(err, camp) {etc});`
`camps.findOne({name: 'John'}, {name: 1, "campaigns[7].campaign_id": 1}, function(err, camp) {etc});`

Here I am trying to retrieve `"campaigns.7.campaign_id": 1` at position 7.
Unfortunately, this is does not return the specific `campaign_id`.

Any suggestions on how to retrieve the object at position 7 inside the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_slice) projection operator to do this:

```js
camps.findOne({name: 'John'}, {
    name: 1, 
    'campaigns.campaign_id': 1, 
    campaigns: {$slice: [7, 1]}
}, ...
```

Comment: That basically answers my question.  How about if I were to `findOneAndUpdate` and `$inc` on the `campaign_id`?  For example, `camp.findOneAndUpdate({name: 'John'}, {$inc: {campaigns.campaign_id: 1}}, {upsert=true})`.  How would `$inc` determine which position to increment?  Should I post this as another question?  thx